# What happens when you update a column which should not be updated? Are rows updated completely?

Tags: postgresql, performance

Let's start with the bottom-line question. Say I have an `UPDATE` statement as following:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    my_column = <some new value>,
       my_other_column = my_other_column
```

Is there a performance penalty for the unnecessary `my_other_column = my_other_column` assignment?

---

Now, to the real scenario. In my case, I have a function `update(a, b)` as following:

```
create function update(integer, integer) returns void as
$$
    UPDATE my_table
    SET    a = case when $1 is not null then $1 else a end,
           b = case when $2 is not null then $2 else b end
$$
language sql volatile;
```

I am wondering what happens when I call `select update(150, null)`. This resolves to:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    a = 150,
       b = b
```

Is there a performance hit for that redundant `b = b` assignment? Are we now re-writing the `b` column, instead of only the `a` column if we were to remove that assignment from the `UPDATE` statement? Or are rows always written as a whole anyway, regardless of the actual updated columns? Or maybe, is the planner or executor smart enough to filter such redundant assignments out?

Comment: Duplicate: [Performance impact of updating target columns with same values ON CONFLICT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223231/performance-impact-of-updating-target-columns-with-same-values-on-conflict)

Comment: So if I read this correctly, it doesn't matter if the `UPDATE` statement contains so-called dummy assignments, the whole row is rewritten anyway. And for the index, writes only happen if the data is actually changed (which is not in case of `b = b` assignment? Did I understand this correctly?